# Let A, B, C and D be placed consecutively on a circle. Let W, X, Y and Z be the midpoints of the arcs AB, BC, CD and DA, respectively.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Show that the chords WY and XZ are perpendicular.

[image: Image of problem]

I've drawn it using Geogebra and it is quite obvious that it is true - regardless of how I manipulate it, I just don't know where to start with proving it.

If I draw line segments WX and YZ I have two similar triangles, but that isn't enough to show that the two segments are perpendicular. Any ideas to get me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I$ be the intersection of $WY$ and $XZ$. Then $$\angle WIX=\angle WZX+\angle ZWY.$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: Do you mean ∠WIX=∠WZX+∠ZWI?

Comment: Yes, edited. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how you got that..

Comment: They are both equal to $180^\circ-\angle WIZ$.

Comment: Nevermind, I was stuck on something else but I got it, all good now.